# The space of all normal covariances matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, normal-distribution

Let $\cal C$ be the space of all $k-$variate normal covariance matrices and $\cal M$ be the set of all $k\times k$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrices.
As we know that if $k=1$ then ${\cal C}={\cal M}$ .
For $k>1$ is  ${\cal C}={\cal M}$ as well? As I know, we always have ${\cal C}\subseteq{\cal M}$, but is it true that ${\cal M}\subseteq{\cal C}$? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the covariance matrix of $X=A \xi$ for a matrix $A$ and a standard $k$-dimensional Gaussian random variable $\xi$. The conclusion follows since any semi-positive symmetric matrix can be expressed as $A A^\top$.

Comment: Great, I know $cov X=AA^T$. Thanks @Alekk